# How to avoid showing the title bar when phonegap app starts on Android?

Tags: android, cordova

I have a splash screen for my phonegap app on android. However, everytime before showing the splash screen, a blank screen with a header bar (an icon with the app name) will be shown before the splash screen. How do I make that disappear?

Answer (score 1):

Try `requestWindowFeature(FEATURE_NO_TITLE)` in your activity's onCreate()  method

Comment: It didn't work. I tried it both before and after super.onCreate() method. I also tried super.setBooleanProperty("showTitle", false); The title bar still appears for a moment before the splashscreen.

Answer (score 1):

if you could go for fullscreen as well then this may help if you add this in your mainfest -

```
<application 
    android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```